# Avoiding eval() in a particular scenario

Tags: javascript, eval

I have read at several places that we should avoid using **eval** in our JavaScript code.
But, i have a scenario, i am not able to remove this. need help with that

```
        var levels=[];
        for(var k=0;k<levels.length;k++){
            var levelsArray={};
            levelsArray["name"]=levels[k].name;
            levelsArray["caption"]=levels[k].caption;
            var prop = levels[k].name;
            eval("levelsArray[\"memberProvider\"]= function (item) { return item." + prop + ";}");
            levels.push(levelsArray);
        }
```

I hope, the code is clear in what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
levelsArray.memberProvider = (function(p) {
  return function (item) { return item[p]; };
})(prop);
```

Comment: I already tried that, results are not same. The first one gives correct result because i tested by individually writing the the values from the loop.
It seems that value of `prop` is getting replaced by the last value always.

Comment: How are you usign `memberProvider()` ? What `item` contains ?

Comment: I am using Infragistics IgniteUI library. here is the link http://www.igniteui.com/pivot-grid/overview
This is used internally by the library. Do not have indepth knowledge. trying now

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/igniteuisamples/jsfiddle-samples/tree/master/EN/HtmlSamples/pivot-grid/binding-to-flat-data-source

Comment: Please give us a fiddle of your use case, so i can work this out. The edit i made should do it tho.

Comment: Yes.. The edited version worked.. Thanks for the answer.